# Programmatically sign into SharePoint Online via Azure AD

Tags: asp.net, azure, sharepoint, azure-active-directory, msal.js

I have an AAD username and password and I'd like to know if I can programmatically sign into Azure AD, and then navigate to a SharePoint Online site that's protected by AAD.

I've been doing a LOT of research and from what I'm gathering, it's not possible to "bypass" the interactive sign in process that Microsoft has put in place when signing into Azure AD.

From personal experience, I know you can acquire an access token, then query GraphApi to bring back user info, or using CSOM (SharePoint Client Side Object Model), you can get metadata about the SharePoint Online site, but this is not what I'm looking for.

**Current Setup**

- SharePoint Online site - single page behind Azure AD.
- AspNetCore 3.0 app - nothing fancy. Just a link that opens a new tab, which calls a controller (insert logic here to solve my problem)

**What have I tried**

- I've tried setting up ROPC userflow on Azure AD B2C - this works well for getting the access token, but how to sign in AAD?
- I've been reading about headless authentication, silent authentication, non-interactive authentication (https://github.com/azure-samples/active-directory-dotnetcore-console-up-v2, https://vincentlauzon.com/2017/01/29/authenticating-to-azure-ad-non-interactively/) but this is all well for acquiring the access token, but this doesn't answer the question.
- I've tried msal.js when when trying to authenticate, this still shows a popup that requires interaction from a user.
- I thought I could try getting the access token and then using an authentication header, add a bearer token to an httpClient, then fetching the SharePoint Online site in the hope that it might bring back cookies, but nope, no joy.

Does anyone know of any method or any ideas that I can try to implement this? I've been banging my head for a week now.

Thanks for the help

Charles

Comment: I assume that you wanna to sign in your sharepoint site without a sign in process, right?

Comment: From my apps, we avoid login by having grant access, so even with delegated permissions, it does not require users to login. i am investigating this right now, and wondering how I can get my WPF desktop app, using WebView2, to authenticate without prompting the users for login.